# Android: Storing html code for access by multiple activities

Tags: android

I have some lengthy html code that I will need to access from mulitple activities. I would like to have it stored in one place so that I can update it easily (as opposed to storing a string in each activity). What is the best way for me to store this html code so that it can be easily accessed by any activity?

Comment: Did you even search for options on Android storage?  Google is what you need, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I searched Google simon

Comment: OK, here's a tutorial http://bit.ly/1wuRZ2F

Comment: I know I shouldn't waste my time responding to this and potentially egging on a troll, but in case anyone else comes here looking for an answer, the link posted by Simon does not resolve the question.

Comment: To demonstrate that I am not a troll, and that you are not even applying the simplest of attempts to answer your own question, here is the first link in that Google search.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html  In what way does that not answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best but practical solution to do this is storing your HTML in string resources. 
Then you may retrieve it simply by calling `getString(R.string.your_html_string)` method in each activity.

Do not forget to use `CDATA` block. Details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

Comment: Thanks, it appears there are a variety of ways and no clear best option. Using string resources sounds like a good option. I'll just have to convert the HTML text so that it can be stored in the xml file.